# Save CIMTableFrameField to JSON with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, cartographic-information-model, table-frame

I am trying to automatically update a layout table frame with a layer previously created from a model.

I am using [CIM toolset](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm). I am able to look for the table frame element and choose the layer to use (`mapMemberURI`), but by default fields are not added the layout table.

As I don't see a way to display all fields by default (CIM toolset then provide a way to delete some fields), I thought I could manually add the fields of interest, save each `CIMTableFrameField` [Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/sdk/api-reference/index.html#topic17079.html) to json using [ToJson Method](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/sdk/api-reference/index.html#topic25342.html), then relaunch my script, call each json file containing the `CIMTableFrameField` and use append method to add the fields to `CIMTableFrame`.

But I don't understand how to use ToJson method.

[image]

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  # my project
m = aprx.listMaps("Map2")[0]  # my map
lyt = aprx.listLayouts('Tabloid_Paysage_Unique')[0]  # my layout

lyt_cim = lyt.getDefinition("V2")  # Get the layout's CIM definition

# 1) look for table frame and fields manually added from ArcGIS Pro layout view

for elm in lyt_cim.elements:  # loop through all layout elements
    if elm.name == "Categorie route":  # my table frame
        elm.mapMemberURI = 'CIMPATH=map2/clip_circul_dissolve1.json'  # set the table/layer to use
        for f in elm.fields:  # Loop through fields of the table frame 
            if f.name == "Categorie" or f.name == "lengthKm":  #my fields of interest
                filename = f.name + '_test.json'
                file = ToJson(f, filename)  # DON'T KNOW HOW TO USE IT

lyt.setDefinition(lyt_cim)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by saving a layout file with all the table frames and fields I want to show, then into my python script:

- calculate statistics and create results layers
- import the layout file to my project
  when I open the layout view, as it was imported after layer creation, it displays table frames correctly.

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

# apply model builder statistics tool

aprx.importDocument(r"C:\Users\...\Layouts\Tabloid_Paysage_Unique_stats.pagx")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts('Tabloid_Paysage_Unique1')[0]

lyt.exportToPDF('stats.pdf')
```